# TypeScript: How can I extend this type that is similar?

Tags: typescript, types, casting

How can I extend the `IUnitedStatesAddress` to `IUnitedStatesWithTerritoryAddress` without repeating myself? The only difference is that `IUnitedStatesWithTerritoryAddress` has `TUnitedStatesTerritoryAbbreviation` added to the `state` field.

```js
// TypeScript Type: United States Address
export interface IUnitedStatesAddress {
  apartmentSuite: string;
  street: string;
  city: string;
  state: TUnitedStatesStateAbbreviation;
  zipCode: string;
  county: TUnitedStatesCounty;
  country: string;
}

// TypeScript Type: United States With Territory Address
export interface IUnitedStatesWithTerritoryAddress {
  apartmentSuite: string;
  street: string;
  city: string;
  state: TUnitedStatesStateAbbreviation | TUnitedStatesTerritoryAbbreviation;
  zipCode: string;
  county: TUnitedStatesCounty;
  country: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I'm pretty sure of is that you can have a base interface (not to be exported) and extend it with your two cases:

```
interface IUnitedStates {
  apartmentSuite: string;
  street: string;
  city: string;
  zipCode: string;
  county: TUnitedStatesCounty;
  country: string;
}

export interface IUnitedStatesAddress extends IUnitedStates {
  state: TUnitedStatesStateAbbreviation;
}

export interface IUnitedStatesWithTerritoryAddress extends IUnitedStates {
  state: TUnitedStatesStateAbbreviation | TUnitedStatesTerritoryAbbreviation;
}
```

Comment: My pleasure, hope it helped